# How to add error log to bash script, that will save all the errors during the script run

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script with multiple functions. I need to add a function that will record and put all errors into error_log.txt with the date of the error in the first line. My teacher also demands that if the script is run several times a day, then it should record the date only once.

How to add the error log function to the script? What command should I use?

Comment: You have already asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65863085/how-to-add-error-log-to-bash-script-that-will-save-all-the-errors-during-the-sc) and it was closed. Please see [ask], understand what a [mre] is, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I've edited it now

Comment: Is it a requirement that the logging must be provided by a function in the bash script? Or would it be fine to just do something like `date > error_log.txt; ./the_script.sh 2>> error_log.txt`?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, it has to be a part of the script. But thank you for your answer. It's really helpful also.

Comment: What does your teacher count as errors?

Comment: Everything that's giving error when running script. Functions, wrong button, you name it